# Make desktop entry for app that requires root privileges

Tags: sudo, gksu

I used gksu before but it seems that it is no longer available. So how can I make something with the same functionality? Obviously I can still run app through the terminal but I don't want to do that.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xampp
GenericName=Localhost Server
Exec=gksu /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/lampp/XAMPP.png
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;Development;
```

Comment: Try using `pkexec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for [`pkexec`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html), the replacement for `gksu` since gnome 3
simply edit your .desktop file with

```
Exec=pkexec /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```