# Make desktop entry for Netbeans with root privileges

Tags: 18.04, launcher, netbeans

I try to make desktop entry like in this post: [Make desktop entry for app that requires root privileges](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045876/make-desktop-entry-for-app-that-requires-root-privileges?newreg=0f8cb6dbc9f642bbb4cf9f812d62c4f0)

but when I modified line in my launcher:

```
Exec= /bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-11.2/netbeans/bin/netbeans"
```

to this:

```
Exec=pkexec /bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-11.2/netbeans/bin/netbeans"
```

Launcher displayed only root password box and nothing else. When I'm typing my password and hit enter nothing is doing. What I should to change? Maybe I can remove "/bin/sh" to work launcher propelly?

Comment: Why do you want to run Netbeans as root?

Comment: I'm editing files on localhost server. Some files have owner "www-data" and these files are forbidden to overwrite by Netbeans. Maybe it is possible to open, edit and save these files without changing permissions?

Comment: Doesn't sound right to me. I suspect you should be editing files outside your web space and then deploying them once you have them right.

Comment: Of course! There are only development instalations on localhost. In my workflow I'm watching changes in frontend. Now I'm customizing some drupal theme and drupal core needs "www-data" owner for files, but I need to edit some css and .tpl files. When I'm copying files it grab me some time.

Comment: Okay be crazy. You could put Netbeans into the www-data group and make it group writable. https://superuser.com/questions/646062/granting-write-permissions-to-www-data-group

Comment: Related: [My answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185418/816190) on a similar question for XAMPP.